# What can I do with my [insert machine name here]? Questions

Tags: discussion, scope

[So this question regarding the Apple II](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/fun-or-interesting-projects-to-do-with-mac-classic-ii?noredirect=1#comment3217_1203) got flagged as off topic for being too broad and primarily opinion based. I agree with that, buut I also feel like it'd be pretty cool to have a list of crazy things you can do with a specific piece of retro hardware.

I'm wondering if the community feels that such questions would be a good fit for the site if they took on the form of a community wiki answer, where there's no rep involved and everyone and anyone can edit and post updates. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

I think the flags on that questions started with [this comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/what-are-some-names-of-professional-music-software-for-the-macintosh-classic-s#comment3076_1828) on a different, also broad question.  Where would it stop?  Would we have a software list for every brand, every model of personal computer?

Even if the community thinks these questions are useful, the problem is a laundry list of answers don't really fit into the Stack Exchange model.  We have this issue on Stack Overflow frequently with link-only answers and framework recommendation questions.

I do think your suggestion of a Community Wiki Q&A pair would be a good experiment to try.  Anyone could edit the list, and we would just need to make sure that people add to the list rather than add additional answers.